# Cannot refactor Android Studio Project

Tags: java, android

I have copied a current project of Android Studio to a new directory. I will be using the same coding for another app.

I open the project in Android Studio, and click on the "Java" folder, but it doesn´t show any files inside (they do appear in the hard-drive).

When I click to "Refactor" the "Java" folder the following message appears "Cannot perform refactoring. Selected directory is not located inside project".

Can someone help me to solve this, thanks.

Comment: Did you "open" or "import" this project?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't import? Damn... Beaten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had imported the project in a non-empty directory.

Follow the following steps:

Suppose you want to cope a project Named: ***MyProject1***

1. Copy the Project from its directory and paste in an empty folder.
2. Make sure you have closed the MyProject1 from Android Studio by clicking *Files>>Close Project*
3. Click on the **Open an Existing Android Studio Project**
4. Locate the new directory, where you have pasted the MyProject1 folder. Recheck if "**MyProject1**" folder itself contains the "MyProject1" folder then it will not work.
5. Now select the ***MyProject1*** folder and go ahead.
6. It will start the gradle build.
7. After successfull build the you can start *refactoring.*